# country code validation with + symbol, Android

Tags: android

In my application users enters mobile number's country code with '+' symbol. Right now I am checking for + symbol. If they enter '+INDIA', according to my code this is correct. But according to logic this is wrong. They needs to enter '+91'. Means they can enter only 1, 2 or 3 digit number with '+' symbol. for example '+1', '+91' or '+234'. How I can achieve this type of validation in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own [Pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to check the format. I could give you the example, but I think the site I linked explains it much better.

It should probably start with something like `\+\d\d?\d?`

Comment: Thanks it's working. I write this  if (countryCodeString.trim().matches("\\+\\d\\d?\\d?")) { and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Google's own implementation of Phone Numbers](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) or this [xml list](https://code.google.com/p/country-phone-codes/).

Hope it helps !

Comment: Sorry but i need to validate country code not phone number.  I am validating phone number by sending sms.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question ! Hope @ndsmyter helped !

Comment: It's Ok. ya he helped me lot. By the help of him i learn new thing.